# Should I install windows 8.1 ?

Tags: c#, android, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I am a .NET developer. I develop applications for desktop and web in c#. Now I am planing to start developing mobile app for windows phone and android. Also I want to continue in desktop and web in c#. 
At this time I am using Windows 7 and VS2012.

My question is that,

- Should I start using windows 8.1 or not for those all things ?
- I am little confuse in this. Is Windows 8.1 comfortable with Java and previous .net versions?
- Should I switch to windows 8.1 or continue with windows 7 ?

Comment: Make sure you have Pro Edition for running Emulators http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows Phone 8+ development requires **Windows 8 Pro or higher**, **64 bit**.

If you're planning on doing Windows phone development, then you **cannot** use Windows 7. It's also important that you review the list of system requirements for the emulators that are commonly used when doing Windows Phone development [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402529%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Also, pay attention to the [hardware requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

You mentioned in a comment that your PC has 4GB of RAM. You may find that doing phone development with emulators is not ideal with that amount of RAM, especially as Windows Phone development requires that the host operating system is 64 bit. In fact, I wouldn't consider using a desktop 64 bit operating system with only 4GB of RAM when doing software development a reasonable development platform for doing phone development, especially if you're also creating web applications and more to work with the phone application. 8GB RAM is the minimum I'd recommend.

For other needs, Windows 8.1 should be more than a sufficient platform for doing the other types of development that you want to continue doing. Java will work and you'll still be able to do traditional desktop development, web development, and create new WinRT Windows Store (Modern) applications within Visual Studio.

If you have any older development platform requirements (like particular older versions of Java or other development tools), verify that they are compatible with Windows 8.1 Pro before upgrading. Development tools often are not.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of .NET and Java you will find no difference, and in addition if you are on Windows 8.1 and VS 2013 you will be able to develop Modern UI applications.

So I would go for 8.1, especially since it is a start down the path of making the Modern UI less intrusive for non-touch users.

Answer (score 1):

You can develop everything, that you develop now on Windows 7, on Windows 8 also. The only thing is that Windows 8 has the start screen and Windows 7 the old startmenue. I would take windows 8 for developing Windows Apps and all other applications

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to design apps for windows store or Asp.net apps that use modern day razor syntax or bootstrap 3, then and only then you need windows 8.1.

Comment: ya but i still need all the old things will work fine like .NET 2,3,3.5,4 . is they work proper in windows 8.1 ?

Comment: Nope. That part is tricky. You can always upgrade a project but once you run them in vs 2013 they can't be run in previous visual studio editions.

Comment: Anyway its time you update as .net 2 is pretty outdated and deprecated too. Plus windows 8.1 is really special to developers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can develop anything which you can with windows 7 additionally you can also develop windows 8.1 & windows 8 phone apps as well. I am windows 8.1 user and Java and .Net everything is fine. Just make sure your machine meet the windows 8.1 system requirements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop Windows Store Apps / or use Windows Runtime in Windows Phone apps then you should switch to Windows 8.1 (Windows Runtime is not available in Windows 7 OS).